# Where is the .JS file in this code? And why are they calling it this way?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

Where is the JS file and is this Async the fastest way to call JS?

I guess they then have PHP calls in the .JS for updating the Ad stats??

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){ 
     var acc = "acc_230d269_pub";
     var st = "nocss";
     var or = "h";
     var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     var d = document.createElement("script");
     d.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ?'https://' : 'http://')+"engine.influads.com/show/"+or+"/"+st+"/"+acc;
     d.type = "text/javascript"; 
     d.async = true;
     d.defer = true;
     e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
 })();
 </script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking as the question are strangely formulated. The js loaded here will be http://engine.influads.com/show/h/nocss/acc_230d269_pub . The async is there so the UI won't block while loading the JS. This way the page is perceived by the user to  load faster. My guess is that the JS is generated dynamically to change the ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made your code more [readable](http://jsbeautifier.org):

```
1 <script type="text/javascript">
2 (function () {
3   var acc = "acc_230d269_pub";
4   var st = "nocss";
5   var or = "h";
6   var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
7   var d = document.createElement("script");
8   d.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
9                "engine.influads.com/show/" + or + "/" + st + "/" + acc;
10  d.type = "text/javascript";
11  d.async = true;
12  d.defer = true;
13  e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
14 })();
15 </script>
```

- 2,14 An anonymous function wrapper is created, so that variables cannot be access from outside the function ("scope")
- 3   `acc` looks like the identifier of the advertiser
- 4,5 `st = "nocss"` and `or = "h"` looks like settings to adjust the appearance
- 7,10-12 A `<script>` tag is created. `async` = Loading the script will not block the execution of the document. `defer=true` prevents the script from not being executed (can be omitted)
- 6,13 The newly created script tag is inserted before *(13)* the first script tag in the document *(6,13)*
- 8,9 The URL is constructed:
  If the current page is transmitted over a secure connection, the injected script will also be transferred over the HTTPS protocol.

The extension of the requested file is omitted. This file could be served using the `application/javascript` MIME type by server configuration.

Comment: Thank you EVERYONE for your comments. What I don't understand though is, the page http://www.davidairey.com/ shows this adcode in use, but the code shows different ads on refresh and there JS code only shows one ad block : http://engine.influads.com/show/h/nocss/acc_230d269_pub so where is the PHP or random calls to load more??

Comment: I just noticed that the JS changes each time you click the link: and it works sometimes with or without http   -  http://engine.influads.com/show/h/nocss/acc_230d269_pub - crazy!

Comment: The ads are randomly generated at the server's side.

Comment: *How is this*? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: How have acheived this? Do you think set a cron job on the server to randomly update the JS files on their server on client and publisher folders???

Comment: That's overkill for such a simple task. What about choosing a random number, and showing the advert attached to that number?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3967/discussion-between-theblackbenzkid-and-rob-w)

Comment: Question - is the code above xHTML valid? Would it work in all documents? HTML5, xHTML strict? iphone/wap - all browsers??

Comment: Yes, the code is fully XHTML strict, and HTML5 valid. See http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

It inserts the script tag with a dynamically constructed file name and puts it in the document before the first script tag. The advantage of this approach is that it will run only when the document is loaded, so it will not block the document loading. This way, the user will experience no (or less) delay. It's a good practise to do this for analytical tools and such, because they don't add functionality for the user and you just want to track their actions. It doesn't matter if you miss one or two of those measurements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to include js code into html, one is put the code directly into the  tag, just like what you wondered about the code you posted, the other method is to use the following syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/external_file.js"></script>
```

As a side note, the code you posted uses a technique that prevents js name spacing conflicts by putting the code in the 
`(function() ...)();` block, which I find to be a very good practice.

Regarding the question about using async in  tag, you might want to take a look at this:
http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

Answer (score 1):

Most of that code is for loading the JavaScript code asynchronously, in a way that works in different browsers. An explanation of how it works is here: http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/

Loading asynchronously means that the browser doesn't wait for it to finish. So the ad won't load faster, but the rest of the page will.

If you piece together the string, you'll find that the JavaScript file they're loading is: http://engine.influads.com/show/h/nocss/acc_230d269_pub

Comment: Thanks man, I combined this with the answer above. Marked it as an answer too for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits I see are:

1. Asynchronous loading that would help in faster rendering of the UI
2. The selective `http` or `https` used for the location of the js source following the protocol that current page is loaded with

I am wondering why the js source would not end with a `.js` extension though

Comment: They used a htaccess modification probably as mentioned above in the answer.