# Javascript PHP document.write

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the .JS file in this code? And why are they calling it this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627519/where-is-the-js-file-in-this-code-and-why-are-they-calling-it-this-way)

This is my JavaScript code. **showcode.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">(function(){
var a="publisher-121";
var n="top";
var z="45";
var h="125";
var w="125";
var nofollow="no";
var e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var d=document.createElement("script");
d.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +"server.com/adcode.php?a="+a+"&h="+h+"&w="+w+"&n="+n+"&z="+z;
d.async = true;
d.defer = true;
d.type="text/javascript";
e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
})();</script>
```

As you can see, the URL points to http://server.com/adcode.php?a=publisher-121&n=top&z=45&w=125&h=125

All this page has is the following: (**adcode.php**)

```
 <?php  echo "document.write('<div id=\"ha_adblock ".$a."_".$z."\" class=\"ha_adblock".$a."_".$z."\" style=\"width:".$h."px;height:".$w."px;background:#eee;text-align:center;cursor:pointer\" onClick=\"window.location.href=\'click.php?a=".$a."&z=".$z."&g=http://refererurl.com/;\'return false;\"><a href=\"http://refererurl.com/\" onClick=\"window.location.href=\'click.php?a=".$a."&z=".$z."&g=http://refererurl.com/;\'return false;\" style=\"color:#333;font-weight:bold\">advert</a></div>');"; ?>
```

However - the page just appears blank. Firebug shows that my code has been loaded and executed fine with no errors. If I just spit out the code above (document.write) inside a script tag it works - the PHP call back does not seem to work?

Comment: What am I missing? I don't see any PHP call.

Comment: The last snippet is wrapped in an echo. There is no issue with my doc.write or echo. I have used \" \" etc. In this sample I am showing for psuedo view.

Comment: Does anything show up on the page at all? If you view source do you see your JavaScript, or is it blank?

Comment: You must have the URL wrong. That URL does not resolve to anything that looks like the output of that PHP script (which is going to be outputting the wrong content-type header for a JavaScript script)

Comment: `'https:'==document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + "example.com/"` could be written more simply as `"//example.com/"`

Comment: The URL is fine. You can see the script here. http://is.gd/Jtk4SW

Comment: Ugh. Use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) for building that js snippet. It'll allow you to format the code nicely, eliminate the need to escape the `"` quotes, and allow you to still insert variables without having to concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `document.write` in a script that is included with `defer` or `async` attributes. Trying to do so is just illogical.

Also, you need to escape the quotes in the string - any editor with colour coding will show you that the attribute contents are not included in the strine, unless you put a `\` before the quotes inside it.

Comment: Even if I remove that, it still does not work. Why is it illogical? Google and most adnetworks do this.

Comment: Google doesn't use `defer` or `async` last I checked, causing them to lock up the entire page while they load. But regardless of that, did you escape your quotes? Have you checked your browser's error console?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly escaping the double-quote characters (`"`) in your PHP file. They should be preceded by backslash (`\`) characters (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)). The PHP script should read:

```
 <?php echo "document.write('<div id=\"adblock\" class=\"ha_adblock121_45\" style=\"width:125px;height:125px;background:#eee;text-align:center;cursor:pointer\" onClick=\"window.location.href=click.php?g=http://refererurl.com/;return false;\"><a href=\"http://refererurl.com/\" onClick=\"window.location.href=click.php?g=http://refererurl.com/;return false;\" style=\"color:#333;font-weight:bold\">advert</a></div>');"; ?>
```

Comment: I already mentioned in my comment in my first post - I escaped it. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

< ?php echo "< script>(function(){document.write('< div id=\"adblock\" class=\"ha_adblock121_45\" style=\"width:125px;height:125px;background:#eee;text-align:center;cursor:pointer\" onClick=\"window.location.href=click.php?g=http://refererurl.com/;return false;\">advert< /a>< /div>');})();< /script>"; ? >

Call automated function that will execute whenever the page loads..:-)